# Can a parametric function have a tangent line at one point, even if its components are not differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric

Given a parametric function such as the following

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
x = x(t) \\
y = y(t) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Can $\lim_{\triangle t \to t_0} {\triangle y \over \triangle x}$ exist even if $x'(t_0)$ and $y'(t_0)$ doesn't?
I confonted this in my analysis textbook and it assumed that when both$x'(t)$ and $y'(t)$ exist while $x'(t) \neq 0$:

$$\lim_{\triangle t \to t_0} {\triangle y \over \triangle x} = {lim_{\triangle t \to 0} {\frac{\triangle t}{x(t_0+\triangle t) -x(t_0)}}\frac{y(t_0+\triangle t) - y(t_0)}{\triangle t}} 
=\frac{\lim _{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{y\left(t_{0}+\Delta t\right)-y_{0}}{\Delta t}}{\lim _{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{x\left(t_{0}+\Delta t\right)-x_{0}}{\Delta t}}
= \frac{y'(t_0)}{x'(t_0)}$$

However $\lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is not always the same as$\frac{\lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} f(x)}{\lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0} g(x)}}$

So potentially x(t) and y(t) can both be undifferentiable while $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ exist, can you help me provide an example of this circumstances?

I was thinking about $x(t) = y(t) = t^{1/3}$, though both x(t) and y(t) are not differentiable at 0, ${y(t)\over x(t)}$ seems to be just a regular straight line and have an
$\lim_{\triangle t \to 0} {\triangle y \over \triangle x}$ at 0. Is this a valide example? And if it is, would you mind provide another example that is not only a straight line? I still did not come up with any yet.

I think this question can also apply to **higher dimensions**. In other words, can the tangent line at a point exist in higher demensions even if one of the components are undifferentiable? Please give me some examples in higher dimensions if possible.

---

Based on the comments below. Such a function do exist, and I’d assume it exists in higher dimensions. So here is my immediately follow up questions. Given r(t) as a vector function in the form of <x(t),y(t),z(t)>. So $r’(t_0)$ is defined as $ \lim _{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{r\left(t_{0}+\Delta t\right)-r\left(t_{0}\right)}{\Delta t} = <x’(t_0), y’(t_0), z’(t_0)>$ Does that mean even a tangent line do exist at t0, the function itself is not differentiable? So does that mean we will loss something when parametrizing a function?

Comment: Your example is valid, as the limit is just $\lim_{t \to 0}1 = 1$. A slightly more (but not by much so) complicated example would be $x$ as your example and $y$ the square of $x$, the resulting limit is $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{y(t)}{x(t)} = 0$.

Comment: If $x$ is a continuous, but not necessarily differentiable, function of $t$, and $y=f(x)$ for some differentiable function $f$, then $\lim_{t\to t_0} \frac{y(t)-y(t_0)}{x(t)-x(t_0)}=\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{y(x)-y(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(x_0)$ where $x_0=x(t_0)$

Comment: @wsz_fantasy: At cusps of a standard cycloid slope is zero while passing from $ -\infty \to +\infty $.

Comment: Let $f(t)$ be any function – even a nowhere continuous function – and consider the parametric equations $x=f(t)$, $y=f(t)$. This is a parametrization of $y=x$, which is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: Any thoughts about the comments, wsz?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks a lot for all these comments. I have edited the question and added some follow-up thoughts.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about what you mean by tangent line (it is an ambiguous notion which precise meaning depends heavily on author). However you may benefit my knowing the lemma that  that a function $r: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ is differentiable at a point $t_0$ if and only if each component function $r_k: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable at $t_0$ for $k \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$. Does this help with your query?

Comment: $x=x(t),y=y(t)$ defines a *relation* between $x$ and $y$; $f(x,y)=0$. $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ defines a *function* from $\bf R$ to ${\bf R}^2$. So your addendum is not a generalization of your original question; it's something entirely different. In the original, we're concerned with $dy/dx$; in the addendum, with $dr/dt$.

Comment: Understood, wsz?

Comment: @GerryMyerson That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Good. You might consider writing up what you now know, to post as an answer to the question.